# WriteAsync Specified method is not supported?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to save files async with progress percent. I have the following code :

```
        public async Task<bool> UploadMultipleFile(List<IFormFile> formFiles)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_isInProgress)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var totalBytes = formFiles.Sum(f => f.Length);

                foreach (var formFile in formFiles)
                {
                    _isInProgress = true;

                    var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

                    await using var fileStream = File.Create(GetUploadPath() +   Path.GetExtension(formFile.FileName));
                    await using var stream = formFile.OpenReadStream();

                    long totalReadBytes = 0;
                    int readBytes;

                    while ((readBytes = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, readBytes);

                        totalReadBytes += readBytes;

                        _completedPercentOfUploadProgress = (int)(totalReadBytes / (float)totalBytes * 100.0);
                        await Task.Delay(10); // It is only to make the process slower
                    }
                }

                _isInProgress = false;

                return await Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(false);
            }
        }
```

but in While Block at `WriteAsync` Method Call I got Specified method Is not supported Error. any idea to fix it?

**Update:**

Instead Of Following Code : `await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, readBytes)`

using: `await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, readBytes)` fixed the Problem, because `formFile.OpenReadStream()` doesn't allow you to write, so we either need to create new memory stream or need to set to create as `fileStream(File.Create method)`

Comment: You have to [enable buffering to allow the stream to be read multiple times](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequestrewindextensions.enablebuffering?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I added `HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();`  in Controller  Action but its not working yet. note that this method is in Class Libaray Project

Comment: Wait a while, let me simulate your scenario

Comment: May I know what do you want to do at the end?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron My Dear Friend I found the problem, the problem is I call  `WriteAsync` method in `formFile.OpenReadStream();`  in this case `WriteAsync` throw expetion because its just for reading. When I called `WriteAsync` in fileStream(File.Create method) it works fine.

Comment: Yes, because `formFile.OpenReadStream()` doesn't allow you to write, so we either need to create `new memory stream` or need to set  to create as `fileStream(File.Create method)`

Comment: Either of the ways would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While Block at WriteAsync Method Call I got Specified method Is not
> supported Error. any idea to fix it? throw expetion because its just for reading. When I called WriteAsync in fileStream(File.Create method) it works fine.

**Why You Are Getting the Error:**

If you debug your `stream = formFile.OpenReadStream();` it only allow read operation. But you are trying to execute write operation inside while loop. that is, `stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, readBytes);` which certainly, this method doesn't allow. You can have a look here:

[image]

**Solution:**

Well, In that case we need to create `new MemoryStream()` inside your while loop which will allow you to execute write operation. You could modify your code snippet as following:

```
             while ((readBytes = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    await ms.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                    
                    totalReadBytes += readBytes;
                    _completedPercentOfUploadProgress = (int)(totalReadBytes / (float)totalBytes * 100.0);
                    await Task.Delay(10); // It is only to make the process slower
                }
```

**Note:** Here we are creating `var ms = new MemoryStream();` because it will allow us `WriteAsync` operation over our `file stream. As you can see below:

[image]